# How to save Listview state in shared preference

Tags: java, android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

Hello friends i am new in android using custom listview with help of arrayadopter when user click on item in listview it change color of the item now i want save this state in  shared preference please help me how can do this here is my code if any expert is here please help me i appreciate your help thanks you in advance

// here i want save state when item color changed

```
    holder.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toasty.success(activity, "PICK COLOR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

          highlight=true;




            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(100);

            ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(activity);
            ArrayList<String>colors=new ArrayList<>();
            colors.add("#e0e0eb");
            colors.add("#ccffff");
            colors.add("#ffe6ff");
            colors.add("#ffffcc");
            colors.add("#ccffcc");
            colors.add("#e6f2ff");
            colorPicker.setColors(colors).setColumns(4).setTitle("HIGHLIGHT VERSE").setRoundColorButton(true).setOnChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnChooseColorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChooseColor(int position, int color) {





//color is change and want save this in sharedperfence

 holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);




                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            }).show();






            return false;
        }
    });




my full adopter class

package bible.swordof.God;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker.ColorPicker;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import static android.support.constraint.Constraints.TAG;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class FullverseAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ALLVERSE activity;

    private List<String> versenumber;
    private List<String>verseid;
    private List<String> verselist;
    private List<String> refernce;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private boolean highlight;


public  String ex="switch";

    //check for availabe language
    int result;


    public FullverseAdopter(ALLVERSE context, int resource, List<String> versenumber, List<String> verselist, List<String> refernce, List<String>verseid) {
        super(context, resource, versenumber);
        this.activity = context;
        this.versenumber = versenumber;
        this.verselist = verselist;
        this.refernce = refernce;
        this.verseid=verseid;



    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return versenumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return versenumber.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.versedisplayrow, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
           holder.versenumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            holder.verselist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.verse);
           holder.addfavoruite=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);


         holder.linearLayout=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.versenumber.setText(versenumber.get(position));

        holder.verselist.setText(verselist.get(position));

holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



    }
});



holder.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toasty.success(activity, "PICK COLOR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

      highlight=true;




        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(100);

        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(activity);
        ArrayList<String>colors=new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("#e0e0eb");
        colors.add("#ccffff");
        colors.add("#ffe6ff");
        colors.add("#ffffcc");
        colors.add("#ccffcc");
        colors.add("#e6f2ff");
        colorPicker.setColors(colors).setColumns(4).setTitle("HIGHLIGHT VERSE").setRoundColorButton(true).setOnChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnChooseColorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChooseColor(int position, int color) {

                holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);




            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        }).show();






        return false;
    }
});
        /*holder.verselist.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                holder.verselist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e0e0eb"));
                return false;
            }
        });*/

//verselist highlight

/*holder.verselist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {






    }
});*/



        //share verse
        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toasty.info(activity, "Sharing a verse.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, refernce.get(position) + ":" + versenumber.get(position) + '\n'   + verselist.get(position));
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                activity.startActivity(sendIntent);

            }
        });

//add in favourite
      holder.addfavoruite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
                    mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                  contentValues.put("id",verseid.get(position));
                  contentValues.put("bookname",refernce.get(position));
                   contentValues.put("versenumber",versenumber.get(position));
                   contentValues.put("verse",verselist.get(position));
                   long check=mDb.insert("favourite",null,contentValues);
                   Log.d("MY_TAG","DB IS NOW "+check);
                   Toasty.success(activity, "Added in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();


                }else {


                    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
                    mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    long delete= mDb.delete("favourite","id=?",new String[]{verseid.get(position)});
                   Toasty.error(activity, "Remove in favouite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                }


            }
        });

       /* textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(activity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "YOUR DEVICE NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
*/



        //My toggle button








       /* holder.speakverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "I AM CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Language not supported or Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {


                    textToSpeech.speak(verselist.get(position), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
            }
        });*/




        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView versenumber;
        private TextView verselist;

        private ImageView share;
        private  ToggleButton addfavoruite;
        private ImageView speakverse;
        private LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            versenumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.versenumber);
            verselist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.verse);
           share = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.share);
            /*speakverse = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.speakverse);*/
        addfavoruite=(ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.adbookmark);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layout);



        }


    }
    public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,  String dbfield, String fieldValue) {

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();

            Toast.makeText(activity, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        cursor.close();


        return true;
    }
    public  void opecolorpicker(){



    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code properly here and then ask!

Comment: @NickBapu i posted my code with comments so easily understand it it custom adopter class

Comment: Hey please look at the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving it is create a new class like this

```
class MySaveInstanceClass {
  static ArrayList<Boolean> selectStatusArray;
}
```

Initialize this array when you get the data as

```
MySaveInstanceClass.selectStatusArray = new ArrayList<>(yourList.size());
```

At this point every value in array will be false. And you have one flag for every list item.

When you set color of your layout just access this array and check the corresponding position.

```
holder.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (MySaveInstanceClass.selectStatusArray.get(posiiton) == true) {
      // set background color
    }
  }
}
```

Now you want to save state. You will have access to that array in your activity too.

There is a lifecycle method `onDestroy()` there you open your shared preference and save it. It will look something like this

```
Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);
//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();
```

Now you have your state saved. access the same shared preference in `onStart()` or `onCreate()` method and get the array and intitialize the class

```
MySaveInstanceClass.selectStatusArray = <array found from shared preference>;
```